# Natural language identification of source-code comments

Tags: nlp

currently I'm researching the natural language identification (NLI) of source-code comments.

I'm testing and comparing the up-to-date algorithms adressing this problem.

Do you know any open-source projects, which have comments in different natural languages? Preferably a well-known one.

Thank you very much,
Timo

Comment: This question is off-topic. But do look at ImageMagick, IIRC it has comments in French.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this [Twitter language detection](http://shuyo.wordpress.com/2012/02/21/language-detection-for-twitter-with-99-1-accuracy/)? Twitter looks similar for code comments - lots of tags, links, incomplete sentences, etc. For mixed languages I'd suggest adding a universal sentence detector and then identifying each sentence.

Comment: Yup. I actually started my research from there. Really a great program. Works really well!